# How to add new row in Datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I use following method to build datasource:

```
BindingList<Person> people = new BindingList<Person>();
foreach (var tag in names)
{
    people.Add(new Person
    {
        Id = tag.ID,
        Name = tag.Name,
        Tag = tag.Ref
    });
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = people;
```

How to add a new row in this GridView?

I tried this, but it reloads all data:

```
 BindingList<Person> people = new BindingList<Person>();


            //set datagridview datasource
            dataGridView1.DataSource = people;
            //add new product, named Cookie, to list ant boom you'll see it in your datagridview
            people.Add(new Person());


            dataGridView1.DataSource = people;
```

Comment: Add another instance of `Person` class to `people` list and bind again. Is this Windows Forms application?

Comment: Can you see my update?

Comment: yes, I can. Is thin winForms app? In which event are you populating DataGridView?

Comment: Yes windows form, yes

Comment: Also I tried this: `BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)this.dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Add(new Person());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're working with WinForms application...

First of all, put `BindingList<Person> people = new BindingList<Person>();` declaration in scope of your class, so that it's visible in all methods.
Then, lets assume you're populating DataGridView on `FormLoad` event, and adding other on `button1_Click`:

So, that should be done like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //declare new persons list here, not in method which loads data into list.
    BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>();

    public Form1()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //your initial loading is here, I  guess
        people = new BindingList<Person>();

        foreach (var tag in names)
        {
            people.Add(new Person
            {
                Id = tag.ID,
                Name = tag.Name,
                Tag = tag.Ref
            });
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = people;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Person p = new Person() 
        {
            Id = 10,
            Name = "NewPersonName",
            Tag = 123
        }
        //you can see that I'm not making new instance of person list, just adding new Person inside
        persons.Add(p);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = people;
    }

}
```

Comment: It works, but it deletes all rows and after add new. But  I need to add new row to exists rows

Comment: From where you get: `dataGridView1.DataSource = people;`?

Comment: make sure you're making inital load only once (this code block that I have put in `Form_Load`)

Comment: I need to merge previous `DataSource` with current

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but I have to guess because you didn't show your code...

Comment: I have this code in anothet method and can not pass to Form-

Comment: One question, how to add row between rows (0, 4)?

Comment: `persons.Insert(1, new Person(){...});` - inserts at index 1 (second place)

Comment: Problem is that when I try to add rows I get error, that there are not columns for adding rows. Because I use `dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();` after reload datagridviw click event

Comment: Can you share an sample for: `persons.Insert(1, new Person(){...});`